# code blocks failed message runing hello code

Tags: parallel-processing, mingw, codeblocks, mingw-w64

I'm trying to run this code and im a beginner at this im really struggling I don't know what to do.

NB: A "MinGW" version of Code::Blocks was used here.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {

  printf ("Hello, world:");
  #pragma omp parallel
    printf (" %d", omp_get_thread_num ());
  printf ("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

[image: this is the message im getting]

Answer (score 0):

Change a debugger setting in the following way.

From the `Settings` menu click on `Debugger...`, then on the left of the screen select `Default`, a debugger type. This should show `Executable paths` set to:

`C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe`

change this to:

`C:\Program Files\Codeblocks\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe`

You should then be able to use the debugger.

---

**NB: Other Information**

The above type of fix is required if you install the "MinGW" version of 'Code::Blocks 20.03' on Windows, using 'codeblocks-20.03mingw-setup.exe' ( the version relevant on 8th April 2021 , with the default installation type used ).