# How do you debug using 'Code::Blocks 20.03' (the "mingw" version)?

Tags: debugging, mingw, codeblocks, mingw-w64

I have built a `Console Application` using `Code::Blocks 20.03`, which was installed using `codeblocks-20.03mingw-setup.exe`. The defaults for the installation directory(see Note01) and the installation type (Full), were used.

I tried to `Debug` by using the `Debug` menu, clicking `Start/Continue`, and debugging failed.

I guess the important information from the log of what happened is

```
Starting the debuggee failed: No executable specified, use `target exec'
```

The full output from trying to debug is given below.

My question is, how do you debug using `Code::Blocks 20.03 (the "mingw" version)`?

Full Output from trying to run a debugging session follows.

---

```
Active debugger config: GDB/CDB debugger:Default
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Selecting target: 
Debug
Adding source dir: C:\CodeBlocks20.03Small\ConsoleApplication\program01INc\
Adding source dir: C:\CodeBlocks20.03Small\ConsoleApplication\program01INc\
Adding file: C:\CodeBlocks20.03Small\ConsoleApplication\program01INc\bin\Debug\program01INc.exe
Changing directory to: C:/CodeBlocks20.03Small/ConsoleApplication/program01INc/.
Set variable: PATH=.;C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Roger\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\FreeFem++;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Roger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts;C:\Users\Roger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32;C:\Users\Roger\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64;C:\texlive\2017\bin\win32;C:\Users\Roger\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;\;C:\Program Files (x86)\clisp-2.49
Starting debuggee: C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args C:/CodeBlocks20.03Small/ConsoleApplication/program01INc/bin/Debug/program01INc.exe
done
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
Starting the debuggee failed: No executable specified, use `target exec'.
Debugger finished with status 0
===============================
```

In building my project I used the defaults from the `Select Compiler` dialog box.

**Note01:**

It looks as if you should (date 11th April 2021) always use the default directory, to install. I installed a version of `Code::Blocks` in `C:\Program Files\CodeBlocksSmall` when I went to uninstall it, the uninstaller would only accept `C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks` as the directory to uninstall from. I deleted the `CodeBlocksSmall` directory manually. I noticed  this behaviour when I installed using `codeblocks-20.03-setup.exe`.

Related question
[Starting the debuggee failed: No executable specified, use `target exec'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66884293/starting-the-debuggee-failed-no-executable-specified-use-target-exec)

## =======================

It looks as if a prior installation of `MinGW` was inadvertently being used by the attempted debugging session(this is no longer possible). See the involvement of the file

`C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe`, in the line

```
Starting debugger: C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args
```

Now when I try to run a debugging session, failure occurs differently (see just after the next four lines).

It looks to me as if I need to at least to change the behaviour indicated by

```
Starting debugger: C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args
```

to behaviour produced by

```
Starting debugger: C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname -quiet -args
```

---

```
Active debugger config: GDB/CDB debugger:Default
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Selecting target: 
Debug
Adding source dir: C:\Codeblocks20.03\ConsoleApp\program01INcForAnswer\
Adding source dir: C:\Codeblocks20.03\ConsoleApp\program01INcForAnswer\
Adding file: C:\Codeblocks20.03\ConsoleApp\program01INcForAnswer\bin\Debug\program01INcForAnswer.exe
Changing directory to: C:/Codeblocks20.03/ConsoleApp/program01INcForAnswer/.
Set variable: PATH=.;C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Roger\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\FreeFem++;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Roger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts;C:\Users\Roger\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32;C:\Users\Roger\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64;C:\texlive\2017\bin\win32;C:\Users\Roger\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\clisp-2.49
Starting debugger: C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args C:/Codeblocks20.03/ConsoleApp/program01INcForAnswer/bin/Debug/program01INcForAnswer.exe
failed
```

---

Another related question is at

[code blocks failed message runing hello code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66409159/code-blocks-failed-message-runing-hello-code/67113390#67113390)

There, the error message is like the one shown just above, and see also below

```
Starting debugger: C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname -quiet -args C:/Codeblocks20.03/ConsoleApp/program01INcForAnswer/bin/Debug/program01INcForAnswer.exe failed
```

Note that, in both cases, `Code::Blocks` is trying to invoke a debugger from the directory `C:\MinGW\bin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get debugging working, the type of fix described here wil be required if you install the `MinGW` version of `Code::Blocks 20.03` on `Windows`, using `codeblocks-20.03mingw-setup.exe` ( the 8th April 2021 version, with the default installation accepted ).

What I did to get it to work was the following.

From the `Settings` menu I clicked on `Debugger..`, then on the left of the screen selected `Default`, a debugger type. This showed me  `Executable paths` which was set to

`C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe`

I changed this to

`C:\Program Files\Codeblocks\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe`

I was then able to use the debugger.